# covering space by circles

Tags: geometry

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice of $\mathbb R^2$. There is a result that says

If when a circle of radius $1$ is centered at each lattice point, the circles will cover all of $\mathbb R^2$ then the area of the fundamental parallelogram $\leq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt3$

Can someone provide me the proof of this or point to a paper or textbook that proofs this result. It's apparently well known.

EDIT: Rephrasing this question:
Consider a parallelogram $P$. Suppose that the distance between any point inside the parallelogram and it's nearest vertex is at most $1$ then the area of the parallelogram $\leq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt3$

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you mean by cover. In the kissing configuration, circles cover as much as possible without intersecting, but not whole space. If you do not care about intersection, taking radius 10 or 55 or 78.9 will still cover the space...

Comment: You have to take radius of 1 and each circle is centered on a lattice point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2d>0$ be the smallest occurring distance between two lattice points. Then $0< d\leq 1$. We may assume that $(\pm d,0)$ are lattice points and that the line $\ell: \ y=h$ is the first horizontal lattice line above $y=0$. By definition of $d$ one necessarily has $$h\geq\sqrt{3} d\ .\tag{1}$$

The point $P:=(0,\sqrt{1-d^2})$ is on the rims of both unit disks with centers $(\pm d,0)$, and these disks do not cover a full neighborhood of $P$. If $P$ had a distance $>1$ from all lattice points on $\ell$ some points in the neighborhood of $P$ would still be left uncovered. It follows that there is a lattice point $(u,h)\in\ell$ with $|u|\leq d$ and
$$|P-(u,h)|^2=u^2+\bigl(h-\sqrt{1-d^2})^2\leq1\ .$$
This implies $h\leq1+\sqrt{1-d^2}$, and together with $(1)$ we obtain that $0<d\leq{\sqrt{3}\over2}$.

It follows that the area $A$ of a fundamental parallelogram satisfies
$$A=2d\>h\leq 2d\bigl(1+\sqrt{1-d^2}\bigr)=:f(d)\ .$$
Maximizing $f$ over $0<d\leq{\sqrt{3}\over2}$ proves that indeed
$$A\leq{3\sqrt{3}\over2}\ ,$$
which corresponds to the regular hexagonal lattice, as expected.

Comment: What is $s$? Do you mean $d$?

Comment: Using geometry software, I can see that "because otherwise some points $(0,\sqrt{1-d^2}+\epsilon)$ would be left uncovered." is true. However, I can't see why it is though.